# If a cell contains mulitple instances of specific text, then extract top 3 of the specified text found in the cell

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, excel-formula

I have a cell in A1 that looks something like this

```
cartoon,high volume,safe,funny
```

ect... There's no real limit on how many values these cells can contain

In another in Column D I have specific strings of the most important ones like so

```
history
science
funny
cartoon
```

ect... This list can also be quite long but currently maxing out at ~50 values.

I want to check to see if the string in A1 has any of the values in column D and if so, return the top 3 values that exist in Column D that match any value in cell A1 as a csv.

So the output for the above example should be the following

```
funny, cartoon
```

Everything I've tried doesn't seem to give me the output I'm looking for but would only provide the first value it finds instead of the top 3 matches.

Any ideas? I'm also open to running a script on this which seems like it would be the best way to do so but I'm not exactly sure where to begin on that.

Thanks!

Comment: What does "top 3 matches" mean?  What have you tried?  Do you want a solution for Excel or for Sheets?

Comment: Excel or GoogleSheets? Must solution apply to both or is there only one it must work in?

Comment: To return as a CSV - that will require a script AFAIK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[google-spreadsheet](/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet) solution:

```
'for a CSV of all matches
=arrayformula(TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(E2:E8, A2)), E2:E8, "")))
'for a CSV of the first three matches
=replace(arrayformula(TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, IF(isnumber(search(E3:E9, A3)), E3:E9, ""))), find("|", substitute(arrayformula(TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, IF(isnumber(search(E3:E9, A3)), E3:E9, ""))), ",", "|", 3)&"|||"), len(A3), "")
```

[image]

[excel-2016](/questions/tagged/excel-2016)[textjoin](/questions/tagged/textjoin) solution:

```
'for a CSV of all matches input as array formula with ctrl+shift+enter
=TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(E2:E8, A2)), E2:E8, ""))
'for a CSV of the first three matches input as array formula with ctrl+shift+enter
=replace(TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, IF(isnumber(search(E3:E9, A3)), E3:E9, "")), find("|", substitute(TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, IF(isnumber(search(E3:E9, A3)), E3:E9, "")), ",", "|", 3)&"|||"), len(A3), "")
```

Comment: This worked like a charm, thanks so much! QQ, in the google sheets formula, why are you searching for " | " ?

Comment: It's used with SUBSTITUTE to truncate off the top 3.

Comment: Oh gotcha. Makes sense. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer to get you started.  You'll have to figure out the second part ("return the top 3 values that exist in Column D") yourself.

On the other hand, what you're describing is very obscure and I can't help but think that this is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378), and that a better solution could be provided if your question contained more information about *where this data is coming from* and the *end result* of what you're trying to do with it.

To start with, data should not be grouped into cells like you're doing, and your issue is exactly why: data is much easier to work with, search, manipulate, etc, if it is properly stored in a logical and **organized fashion**...  in Excel that starts with having no more than **one "piece" of data per cell**.

---

For the first half of your problem, one way to compare a list of values to a single cell, to return `True`/`False` if any of the values exist within the cell, you could use an **array formula* with `FIND`, `IFERROR` and `SUM`.

If cell `A1` contains `cartoon,high volume,safe,funny` and cells `D1:D4` contain `history,science,funny,cartoon` then you could use this array formula, for example in `B1`:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(FIND($D$1:$D$4,A1),0))>0
```

To make this function as an **array formula**, you'll need to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to enter the formula (instead of just hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>.)

This will return `TRUE` since the value exists.  You could have more sets of strings in the cells below `A1` and copy or "fill down" the formula in `B1` to return `TRUE` or `FALSE` as appropriate.

[image: img]

The second part, of returning only the top 3 values that exists in the other set of cells will be a bit more tricky unless you write a custom VBA function, or better yet, separate the data into separate cells *like the Microsoft gods intended.*

---

### More Information:

- Chip Pearson : [**Array Formulas**](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/arrayformulas.aspx)
- Office Support: [**Create an array formula**](https://support.office.com/article/create-an-array-formula-e43e12e0-afc6-4a12-bc7f-48361075954d)
- Office Support: **[Guidelines and examples of array formulas](http://support.office.com/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7)**